# Parse date with time zone, skip timezone

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I try to parse date from string which contains time zone information. Input string is `2014-12-17T08:05:39+00:00`.

I use `DateTime.Parse()` method which return me `2014-12-17 09:05:39` (one hour was added). I live in `UTC+1:00 (Warsaw)`, so .NET adopt this date to my local time.

My question is how to use the parse method while skipping time zone, for example for `2014-12-17T08:05:39+00:00` I want to get `2014-12-17 08:05:39`.

Comment: If you want to avoid hard-to-find bugs with your time zone handling code, I'd recommend you take a look at NodaTime.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend parsing it as a `DateTimeOffset` instead of as a `DateTime`. You can then get the `DateTime` out of that, but it separates the "parsing the data you've been given" step from the "only using the bits I want from that" step.

It's possible that there are ways to make `DateTime.Parse` behave the way you want using `DateTimeStyles` - and I'm surprised it's converting to a "local" kind automatically anyway - but using `DateTimeOffset` will make it clearer.

(Of course I'd *really* recommend using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) instead, parsing to an `OffsetDateTime` and then getting the `LocalDateTime` out of that, but that's a different matter...)

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the part specifying time zone in input string then it parses directly without adjusting to local time. The `date.Kind` is then `Unspecified`.

```
var input = "2014-12-17T08:05:39";
var date = DateTime.Parse(fixedInput);
```

Although this works you might want to have a look on NodaTime as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `DateTimeOffset` instead of the `DateTime`

```
DateTimeOffset result = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2014-12-17T08:05:39+00:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

it gives you : `12/17/2014 8:05:39 AM +00:00`